# Verify FPFile authenticity

Tags: filepicker.io

I use filepicker.io on the client to get the FPFile object, then I send this object to the server. How can the server verify that the FPFile object is authentic? Shouldn't there be an easy way to do this, say, with an HMAC signature? I can't find any documentation for this.

UPDATE:

Ideally, I would like to verify that the file was:

1. Uploaded using my API key.
2. Uploaded by the same guy who is sending me the FPFile in an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be via validating that the filepicker url and metadata in the FPFile matches what is returned via the /metadata endpoint, for example

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/JhJKMtnRDW9uLYcnkRKW/metadata

Comment: Does this confirm that the file indeed belongs to you?

Comment: By belongs to you, do you mean was uploaded by your API key?